# Google Tag manager not firing the collect url

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am fairly new to GTM and trying to figure out something here.

This is the url where i have set up gtm:

http://pizza.de/order/testshop/5283/index.htm

If you see at console, dataLayer is correctly set. So there is no problem with dataLayer, however i don't see the collect.js url firing. I am very sure that the configuration is correct but not able to figure out why the dataLayer is not being pushed to the server.

Any help will with greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nyuen, was for responding late. Was AFK. Unfortunately, that didn't help. I made a small application running on localhost and tried to create the same scenario.

```
Variables pushed to the data layer (i.e. using dataLayer.push()) after the container snippet will not be able to fire tags on page loads with a matching condition.
```

The above is correct, but however i realized that it still fires no matter where you  place the dataLayer, but its better to follow the documentation.

What I realized is that, **gtm.js** is responsible to fire **analytics.js** and **analytics.js** is responsible to fire the events. In my case, due to some unknown reason, analytics.js was not loading at all. So I had to inject this script and then the events started firing.

Answer (score 1):

Move your dataLayer.push code to come before the GTM container tag. You are pushing to the dataLayer afterwards, so the GTM container is not able to use it.

From this:https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en

> Variables pushed to the data layer (i.e. using dataLayer.push()) after the container snippet will not be able to fire tags on page loads with a matching condition.